# Replace two column values in another df for corresponding column values in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframe such as :

**Tab1**

```
COL1   COL2     COL3 
Sp1    False    A
Sp2    False    B 
Sp3    True     X 
Sp4    True     X 
Sp5    False    A 
Sp6    False    C
```

**Tab2**

```
COL1 COL2_bis COL3_bis 
Sp1  True     X
Sp4  True     F
Sp6  True     X
```

And I would like to correct the **Tab1** `COL2` and `COL3` columns compared to **Tab2** `COL2_bis` and `COL3_bis` columns for corresponding `COL1` values between the two tabs.

I should then get:

**Tab1**

```
COL1   COL2     COL3 
Sp1    True     X
Sp2    False    B 
Sp3    True     X 
Sp4    True     F 
Sp5    False    A 
Sp6    True     X
```

Does somene have an idea please ?

Here are the table in dict format if it cna helps:

**tab1:**

```
{'COL1': {0: 'Sp1', 1: 'Sp2', 2: 'Sp3', 3: 'Sp4', 4: 'Sp5', 5: 'Sp6'}, 'COL2': {0: False, 1: False, 2: True, 3: True, 4: False, 5: False}, 'COL3 ': {0: 'A', 1: 'B ', 2: 'X ', 3: 'X ', 4: 'A ', 5: 'C '}}
```

**tab2:**

```
{'COL1': {0: 'Sp1', 1: 'Sp4', 2: 'Sp6'}, 'COL2_bis': {0: True, 1: True, 2: True}, 'COL3_bis ': {0: 'X', 1: 'F', 2: 'X'}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) by `COL1` with set to indices and remove `_bis` substrings from columns names:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('COL1')
df2 = df2.set_index('COL1').rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('_bis', ''))

df1.update(df2)
print (df1)
       COL2 COL3
COL1            
Sp1    True    X
Sp2   False    B
Sp3    True    X
Sp4    True    F
Sp5   False    A
Sp6    True    X

df = df1.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

Rename columns of `df2`, concatenate the two dataframes and drop duplicates based on `COL1`:

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.replace('_bis', '')
out = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates('COL1', keep='last') \
        .sort_values('COL1').reset_index(drop=True)
print(out)

# Output:
  COL1   COL2 COL3
0  Sp1   True    X
1  Sp2  False    B
2  Sp3   True    X
3  Sp4   True    F
4  Sp5  False    A
5  Sp6   True    X
```